# Scrolling only works when mouse is over content

Tags: css, scroll, mouse-position

I am working on a special blog for a client. The posts are aligned next to each other and you can navigate to them with javascript. The user can scroll up and down if the content exceeds the window height. Therefore I put the posts inside a big parent-div with `overflow-y: scroll; overflow-x: hidden;`. But now it seems that for some reason you can only scroll down when the mouse is over the content of a post. Do you guys have any idea how I can do this so that you can scroll down regardless of your mouse position on the parent-div?

Example here: http://interactiewerk.nl/me-myself-and-i/uit-de-schulp

Comment: you want to only scroll one item on the page, regardless of where the position of the mouse is? that sounds like a bad idea.

Comment: No, I want the parent-div of the posts to be scrollable, but now it only seems to scroll when you position the mouse over the content, for example, the text of a post, while the parent-div is as big as the screen. I want the parent-div to be scrollable regardless of the mouse position on the parent-div.